# How to change mode in Vim more effiently

Tags: vim

Most advice point to change escape to jj. I usually scroll through down a file by pressing j repeatedly. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to map `jj` to escape **in insert mode only**.  So unless you tend to type `jj` while inserting text, this should not conflict with normal usage.  The standard way to do it is:

```
 inoremap jj <Esc>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to exit insert mode. I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is not that bad.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get your question, but moving around in Vim can be done really efficiently

- You know the <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd>, but you can type any number N and then the motion to repeat it. Suppos you type <kbd>100j</kbd> you move 100 lines down
- You can also use <kbd>pg up</kbd> and <kbd>pg dn</kbd>
- You can use marks to easily return to a location you were in previously:

  - `:mark a` or <kbd>ma</kbd> to create a bookmark (you can create as many as you want)
  - <kbd>'a</kbd>: return to the line of the bookmark. And <kbd>"a</kbd>: return the the line *and* the column.
- You can go to any line number N, by either `:100`, <kbd>100G</kbd>, or <kbd>100gg</kbd> to go to line number 100.
- If you want to go to line number 100, you can also open it from the command line `$ vi file +100`

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key) and [this image](http://blog.jobbole.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/ADM3A-keyboard.jpg).

The image is just to show why <kbd>ESC</kbd> was chosen.